# WCF4 hosting in IIS, WSDL: bindingNamespace is never read

Tags: wcf, iis, wsdl

In trying to remove the "tempuri" references from a wsdl file. I have followed all existing advice I can think of. Add a

```
[ServiceBehavior(Namespace="mynamespace")]
```

attribute to the implementation class, Add a

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace="mynamespace")]
```

to the contract interface and change the "bindingNamespace" attribute for the end point in the web.config to match.  Yet when loaded (in IIS) the bindingnamespace never gets changed .. its ALWAYS tempuri.

Does anyone have any other thoughts on fixing this problem?  Below is the sample from the web config...the bindingnamespace is never, no matter what i do, updated to be mynamespace, its always tempuri.org.  If, after loading the endpoints via a host factory, I iterate through the bindings in the host description and update them, they will change, but that seems like a hack.

for a service at: "http://mydomain.com/MyService.svc" the following represents my end point configuration, does this even get used by IIS?

```
<services>
  <service name="ServiceImplementationClassReference,MyAssembly" >
    <endpoint name=""
              address="MyService.svc"
              binding="basicHttpBinding"
              bindingNamespace="mynamespace"
              bindingConfiguration=""
              contract="IMyContract" />

    <endpoint name="mexHttpBinding" 
              address="mex"
              binding="mexHttpBinding"
              contract="IMetadataExchange" />        
  </service>
</services>
```

Relavent pieces of generated WSDL file that still reference tempuri.org

```
  <wsdl:import namespace="http://tempuri.org/" location="http://mydomain.org/MyService.svc?wsdl=wsdl0" />
```

........

```
  <wsdl:service name="Directory">
    <wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_IDirectoryServices"
    binding="i0:BasicHttpBinding_IDirectoryServices">
      <soap:address location="http://mydomain.org/MyService.svc" />
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
```

in the wsdl:definition node the xml namespace i0 (as referenced by the service listed above) is also set to tempuri.org, hence the need for the import statement.  There is no change in the use of temprui if i Use BasicHttpBinding or wsHttpBinding. In fact, setting the binding to wsHttpBinding in the web.config file still results in the output above, referencing BasicHttpBinding_IdirectoryServices.

Thanks!

Comment: Ladislav, Yes this is .NET 4.0;   I have added the relevant portions of the wsdl file, hopefully this helps.  The whole thing is far to jumbled to post correctly.  I'd be more than happy to send the full thing to anyone that might find it useful.  Thanks!! I appreciate your assistance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Seems like a known issue: https://connect.microsoft.com/wcf/feedback/details/583163/endpoint-bindingnamespace?wa=wsignin1.0

Here's a chop of my web.config.  Do note that I'm limiting my usage to HTTPS, so YMMV with what you might need to do:

```
    <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="Secure" />
        </endpointBehaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="MetadataBehavior">
                <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <services>
        <service name="Company.Services.Implementation.Service" behaviorConfiguration="MetadataBehavior">
            <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="Secure"
                      binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="httpsBinding" bindingNamespace="http://services.company.com"
                      contract="Company.Services.Interfaces.IService" />
            <endpoint address="mex" behaviorConfiguration="Secure"
                      binding="mexHttpsBinding" bindingConfiguration="httpsBinding" bindingNamespace="http://services.company.com"
                      contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="httpsBinding">
                <security mode="Transport" />
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
        <mexHttpsBinding>
            <binding name="httpsBinding" />
        </mexHttpsBinding>
    </bindings>
```

Here's a code-wise solution from [Raffaele Rialdi](http://blogs.ugidotnet.org/raffaele/archive/2011/02/10/la-soluzione-definitiva-al-namespace-tempuri.org-in-wcf-4.aspx) (slightly modified by me):

```
/// <summary>
/// Attribute which will add a binding namespace to every endpoint it's used in.
/// </summary>
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public sealed class BindingNamespaceBehaviorAttribute : Attribute, IServiceBehavior
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The binding namespace;
    /// </summary>
    private readonly string bindingNamespace;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="BindingNamespaceBehaviorAttribute"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="bindingNamespace">The binding namespace.</param>
    public BindingNamespaceBehaviorAttribute(string bindingNamespace)
    {
        this.bindingNamespace = bindingNamespace;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the binding namespace.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The binding namespace.</value>
    public string BindingNamespace
    {
        get
        {
            return this.bindingNamespace;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Provides the ability to pass custom data to binding elements to support the contract implementation.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="serviceDescription">The service description of the service.</param>
    /// <param name="serviceHostBase">The host of the service.</param>
    /// <param name="endpoints">The service endpoints.</param>
    /// <param name="bindingParameters">Custom objects to which binding elements have access.</param>
    public void AddBindingParameters(
        ServiceDescription serviceDescription,
        ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase,
        Collection<ServiceEndpoint> endpoints,
        BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Provides the ability to change run-time property values or insert custom extension objects such as error
    /// handlers, message or parameter interceptors, security extensions, and other custom extension objects.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="serviceDescription">The service description.</param>
    /// <param name="serviceHostBase">The host that is currently being built.</param>
    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Provides the ability to inspect the service host and the service description to confirm that the service
    /// can run successfully.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="serviceDescription">The service description.</param>
    /// <param name="serviceHostBase">The service host that is currently being constructed.</param>
    public void Validate(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
        if (serviceHostBase == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("serviceHostBase");
        }

        foreach (var endpoint in serviceHostBase.Description.Endpoints)
        {
            endpoint.Binding.Namespace = this.bindingNamespace;
        }
    }
}
```

use like:

```
[ServiceBehavior(Namespace = "http://schemas.vevy.com/Printing")]
[BindingNamespaceBehavior("http://schemas.vevy.com/Printing")]
public class LabelsService : ILabelsService
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Awesome, at least there is a reason! Thanks Jesse, I had not thought to look there,  I hadn't anticipated it being a bug in the architecture.

Comment: Though I am curious as to why the <service> node doesn't seem to be read at all.  For example I can remove the reference to the mex end point and the service still serves up wsdl data with out any trouble, so long as I have a service behavior defined with an empty nam. Removing the empty name, so as to make it a named instance disables the metadata, but applying this named instance as the behaviorConfigruation for the <service> does nothing.  Its as if the simplified configuration of WCF 4 is not being overridden by the items within the web.config =/

Comment: Further research says this is by default: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358768.aspx   How does one go about overriding this to force  IIS to use the web.config configured end points, is the only way to implement a custom host outside of IIS?

Comment: I just tried this out on a service I made and did *not* get the tempuri.org issue.  What I do have is a pretty full web.config.  See my update to the answer to see if this helps you.

Comment: Instresting. Just to note, I am using WCF4 and i suspect i am battling the new "simplified configuration" defaults that are built into it.  I can configure my endpoints very similar to the way you have it , i can even make a mistake in behavior and binding configuration naming and get an error to be produced ("no suchAndSuch behavior exists").  That tells me the config file is being read and parsed.  Its just never then used.  IIS seems locked into using every default in place: reading *.svc files and latching on to a serviceBehavior with name="".

Comment: btw, using address="myService.svc", address="", or address="http://mydomain.org/myService.svc" in the end point seems to yields the same results...regardless of what it is.

Comment: I have made a few discoveries that might help, they have enlightened me thats for sure. I will update if i find more.  The missing piece might have been that my service implementation class and my interface contract were both defined in a separate DLL, then referenced into the web project.  It works, save for the issue mentioned here.  On a whim, I moved those two objects (implementation class and associated service contract) into the web project so as to not have to provide an assembly name in the type string. Oddly enough, it fixed everything and wired it up perfectly (no more tempuri).

Comment: Huh - I'm about in the same configuration - I have an implementation assembly and then the WCF assembly.  I'm wondering since I have the WCF service as a light wrapper (it also implements the same interface) around the business logic that that kept it flush.  Thanks for the info.

Comment: Last bit of text to close the matter.  It is not the physical location of the objects that matter, doing so just solved the issue as well; its the name attribute of the <service> node that was my problem.  I was referencing it as "Type, Assembly" when in fact it is NOT a type string.  Its simply a string based name that happens to share the same name as the type that is implemented in my .svc file.  Removing the assembly portion from the web config and just referencing it by full type name allowed the wiring to succeed and the use of the config settings to follow through.  Thanks Jesse!!

Comment: Just added a quick code-wise solution from a MVP that allows you to decorate your implementation classes with an attribute that will tie the binding namespace to the endpoints automatically without having to specify the "expanded" web.config.

Comment: The `BindingNamespaceBehaviorAttribute` is what made the difference for me - great answer to some serious code smell.  Something this basic (no pun intended) and pervasive should not be this difficult to work with.